# negate boolean function in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to negate a boolean function?

Such that using something like:

```
 _.filter = function(collection, test) {
    var tmp = []
    _.each(collection, function(value){
      if (test(value)) {
        tmp.push(value);
      }
    })
    return tmp
  };   

var bag = [1,2,3];
var evens = function(v) { return v % 2 === 0};
```

This is wrong:

```
// So that it returns the opposite of evens
var result = _.filter(bag, !evens);
```

result:

```
[1,3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making a function that returns a function:

```
function negate(other) {
  return function(v) {return !other(v)};
};
```

Used like this:

```
var result = _.filter(bag, negate(evens));
```

Or just declare a function when you call it:

```
var result = _.filter(bag, function(v) {return evens(v)});
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this. I used `function(v) {return !evens(v)}`

Answer (score 6):

Underscore has a `.negate()` API for this:

```
_.filter(bag, _.negate(evens));
```

You could of course stash that as its own predicate:

```
var odds = _.negate(evens);
```

then

```
_.filter(bag, odds);
```